# Using marks with dead keys

Tags: cursor-movement, keyboard-layout, mark

I am using a keyboard layout in which the backtick (`` ` ``) is a [dead key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout#Dead_keys).

This means that when I type a backtick followed by a vowel (for example `` `a ``) what Vim sees is an accented character (`à`). So if I set a mark with `ma` I can jump to the line of the mark with `'a`. But jumping to the specific location of the mark with `` `a `` won't work.

I found a workaround for this: when typing a dead key I can make Vim receive a backtick by striking the backtick and then the space bar. So if I want to go to mark `a` I type `` `␣a ``.

Is there a way to jump to the mark without having to strike that extra space? With no side effects?

Comment: Can't use type 2 backticks to get a backtick? Or configure your OS to do that? That's still an extra keystoke, but better than ` + space ...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker No. Typing two backticks normally results in \`\` for me. But in Normal mode it seems like another thing happens: I type  \`\`a and Vim says "E78: Unknown mark." From `showcmd` I think Vim understands this as \`à. Also I would like to make the behaviour OS independent. `map` seems to do the work.

Comment: On a German Mac keyboard I have the same problem with `^`, so in order to jump to the begin of a line, I have to hit `^␣`, because it annoyingly is looking for the opportunity to write something like `â`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try making it a mapping:

```
" Mapping dead keys in normal mode
nmap á 'a
```

That way, when Vim gets the accented a, it interprets it as <kbd>`</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

Using `nmap` allows this to happen in normal mode only; in insert mode or command mode, you'll get the accented `a` as you'd expect.

It is possible to apply this to other keys:

```
nmap à `a
nmap Á 'A
nmap À `A
nmap ç 'c
nmap Ç 'C
nmap é 'e
nmap è `e
nmap É 'E
nmap È `E
nmap í 'i
nmap ì `i
nmap Í 'I
nmap Ì `I
nmap ó 'o
nmap ò `o
nmap Ó 'O
nmap Ò `O
nmap ú 'u
nmap ù `u
nmap Ú 'U
nmap Ù `U
```

Comment: This does work. And with no side effects. I should learn to use maps. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Comment: What about the ^ (soft first character of the line)? Since this is a standalone command, what can be done? Does the OS cache the dead key until another key is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

```
" US-intl keyboard dead key re-mappings
nmap à `a|nmap á 'a
nmap ć 'c
nmap è `e|nmap é 'e
nmap ǵ 'g
nmap ì `i|nmap í 'i
nmap ḱ 'k
nmap ĺ 'l
nmap ḿ 'm
nmap ǹ `n|nmap ń 'n
nmap ò `o|nmap ó 'o
nmap ṕ 'p
nmap ŕ 'r
nmap ś 's
nmap ù `u|nmap ú 'u
nmap ǜ `v|nmap ǘ 'v
nmap ẁ `w|nmap ẃ 'w
nmap ỳ `y|nmap ý 'y
nmap ź 'z
```

Comment: Hi, welcome here. I think you could provide some explanation to describe why your answer is useful, and how it solves the problem :)