# Why is navigation to mark a ('a) not working?

Tags: mark

I'm using Vim 7.4.1825, huge version without GUI on OSX.

When I start Vim with `Vim -u NONE`, navigating to mark a - set with `'a` - is not working. Every other mark (b-z) is working well, only jump to mark a is not possible. I can see with `:marks` that `a bar foo` is set, but I cannot jump to it. Is there a explanation for this behavior?

Comment: How do you jump to that mark?

Comment: @romainl With 'a or `a ... both not working.

Comment: Isn't it simply a plugin or a config which remaps `'a`? You can check with `:nmap`.

Comment: Also, does `:normal! 'a` work?

Comment: Yes, `:normal! 'a` works ... hmhm? Why not `'a`? I don't understand it.

Comment: Does it still work when you remove the bang `:normal 'a`? If not, then maybe a mapping is interfering as @statox said (look at `:verb nmap 'a`). Otherwise, maybe something is intercepting the keystrokes `'a` before Vim (your terminal emulator, your window manager, ...). See in their configuration if `'a` is not already bound to some function.

Comment: @user9433424 It works without bang too. You're right, there must be a problem with osx terminal.app. I switched to iTerm2, now it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is *possibly* an issue with [dead keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key), a way of using a "regular" keyboard to provide a way to generate diacrtics such as: `á`, `í`, or `ó`.

One way to test this would be to enter `'a` in your terminal proper (rather than `vim` *within* your terminal) and see what character is produced.

If it *does* produce a diacritic, that means the terminal may well be getting to the keyboard stream before `vim` does, and all `vim` will see is the diacritic rather than the expected key sequence.

If that is the case, you could opt to [switch to another terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455799/how-can-i-eliminate-dead-keys-on-mac-os-x-with-international-keyboard) which better allows you to control this, or there is at least one [solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/803/using-marks-with-dead-keys) here which sneakily map the diacritic back into the correct key sequence that `vim` will process.