# Why do I have to press the caret button twice to go to the beginning of the line?

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode, cursor-motions

When I press the caret button in normal mode, vim first prints a caret at the cursor position. Only with the second press of the caret button does the cursor actually move to the beginning of the line. The caret character then disappears.

[image]

I remember the cursor moving to the beginning of the line immediately the last time I used vim. Is this expected behavior? If yes, how can I tell vim to move to the beginning of the line immediately?

The Vim extension of Visual Studio Code replicates this behavior.

- Vim 8.0.1365
- no .vimrc
- macOS 10.14.6
- German keyboard layout, but it happens with an english layout as well

**EDIT**: `:verbose map ^` yields `No mapping found`

Comment: If you want to enter a `^` as text, do you need one or two key presses?

Comment: I need just one. But in contrast to other characters the cursor turns yellow (as in the GIF) and I can replace it with a circumflexed vowel by typing a vowel character next. Maybe this means that the character has not been printed yet as typing a caret could be just the first step of writing a letter with a diacritic circumflex. Maybe this has something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the `^` being a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key). A dead key doesn't insert a character, but composes a character with the key pressed next.

This is the "normal" keyboard layout in some languages. In a german layout the `^` is a dead key. A example usage is `^a` which would produce a `â`.

This happens in the keyboard driver. So, to get a `^` delivered to Vim you need to enter `^^`.

I have such a layout on one of my work machines, very annoying.

BTW: For German, Linux has a special keyboard layout called "German (no dead keys)". This might also exist for your OS.

Also check this [question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/803/using-marks-with-dead-keys) about problems with the backtick.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. I could fix it with https://github.com/oschrenk/keylayout-de_DE-no-deadkeys. Unfortunately as the problem is caused on the OS level there seems to be no way to deactivate dead keys only in normal mode.

Comment: @303 Correct, no way. If you want to enter this type of characters in Vim, use digraphs. See `:help digraph` and `:help digraph-table`.

Answer (score 0):

I ussualy use `SHIFT + A` end of line and insert, and `SHIFT + I` beggining of line and insert. There are also `$` and and `0` to move to the end and beghining of a line.